# DevExpress GridView ExportToXls/Xlsx not working

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gridview, devexpress, export-to-excel

I´m currently trying to export my GridView1 to an XLS- and XLSX-File. My Problem is, that the export is not working. I just get an empty file and the following error:

[image: Export-Error]

And I can´t find anything regarding this error..

My code is pretty basic:

```
           Case "barXLS"
                fileName = $"C:\Temp\{dt.Year}{dt.Month}{dt.Day}{dt.Second}_Export.xls"
                GridView1.ExportToXls(fileName)
            Case "barXLSX"
                fileName = $"C:\Temp\{dt.Year}{dt.Month}{dt.Day}{dt.Second}_Export.xlsx"
                GridView1.ExportToXlsx(fileName)
```

But I tried a lot of settings for the GridView and for XlsExportOptionsEx but none of them worked. When I try to open the XLS-Sheet I get an error saying that the file is corrupted.

I would really appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: From the part of the exception it seems to me there is a problem with your binding, like some unbound column in the gridview or something ? Did you also wrote this problem in the support of devexpress ?

Comment: As far as I know I don´t have any unbound columns.. And not yet, but I´m currently writing my ticket.

Comment: Could you check the version of the project reference dlls with xtragrid version as 21.1?In v21.1 and higher, the UnboundType property is hidden. https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.UnboundType

Comment: It´s the DevExpress.XtraPrinting.v21.1 dll and the XtraGrid Version is als v21.1. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Ohh, thank you for your comments! I added "columns(i).UnboundDataType = GetType(<DATATYPE>)" to my Column-Definitions and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following line to my column-defintions:

```
columns(i).UnboundDataType = GetType(<DATATYPE>)
```

After that the export worked as expected.